# Draggable/scrolling grid in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a "world map" dragable to all sides.
I have a set of coordiantes in my database, and when i got to my world map view, it centers on 0, 0 coordinate, and loads 2 tiles to the left, right, up and down.

I'm now trying to make this grid of tiles draggable, so if i drag the map down, new tiles are loaded on the top side of the map. And when i get to the "edge" of the map, i want it to seamlessly scroll over to the bottom of the map.

However, my current issue seems to be that when i drag on the tiles, the grid breaks, and the layout of it gets all messed up, so instead of keeping a nice square, it will "remove" columns/rows, breaking the whole map. And i dont really have an idea on how to make the make scroll over to the opposite side when i reach the edge.

Any help here would be greatly appreaciated.

This is my "Map.tsx".

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import authHeader from "../../services/auth-header";

import "../../css/worldMap.css";

interface Coordinate {
  x: number;
  y: number;
  fieldId: string;
}

const Map: React.FC = () => {
  const [mapData, setMapData] = useState<Coordinate[]>([]);
  const [mapPosition, setMapPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const dragAreaSize = 64;

  useEffect(() => {
    getWorldMap();
  }, []);

  const getWorldMap = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/game/worldMap", { headers: authHeader()});
      setMapData(response.data.coordinates);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching map data:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleMouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    setIsDragging(true);
    startX = event.clientX;
    startY = event.clientY;

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
  };

  let startX: number;
  let startY: number;
  let animationFrameId: number | null = null;

  const handleMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    if (!isDragging) return;

    if (!animationFrameId) {
      animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const deltaX = event.clientX - startX;
        const deltaY = event.clientY - startY;

        setMapPosition(prevPosition => ({
          x: prevPosition.x - deltaX * 0.05,
          y: prevPosition.y - deltaY * 0.05,
        }));

        startX = event.clientX;
        startY = event.clientY;
        animationFrameId = null;
      });
    }
  };

  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setIsDragging(false);
    if (animationFrameId) {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
      animationFrameId = null;
    }
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
  };


  const renderMap = () => {
    const minX = -2 + mapPosition.x;
    const maxX = 2 + mapPosition.x;
    const minY = -2 + mapPosition.y;
    const maxY = 2 + mapPosition.y;
  
    return mapData.map((coordinate, index) => {
      if (
        coordinate.x >= minX &&
        coordinate.x <= maxX &&
        coordinate.y >= minY &&
        coordinate.y <= maxY
      ) {
        const adjustedX = coordinate.x - minX;
        const adjustedY = coordinate.y - minY;
  
        return (
          <div
            className={`tile field${coordinate.fieldId}`}
            key={index}
            style={{
              gridColumn: adjustedX + 1,
              gridRow: adjustedY + 1,
            }}
          >
            {`(${coordinate.x}, ${coordinate.y})`}
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="world-map-container" onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>
      <div className="drag-container">
        {/* Render tiles based on mapPosition */}
        {renderMap()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export default Map;
```

This is my "worldMap.css".

```
.world-map-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 84px); 
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, 84px); 
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 420px;
  }

  .drag-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 95%; 
    height: 95%; 
    cursor: grab; 
    -webkit-user-drag:  none; 
  }
  
  .tile {
    width: 84px;
    height: 84px;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .field1 {
    background-color: #3957d8;
  }

  .field2 {
    background-color: #19961f;
  }

  .field3 {
    background-color: #505153;
  }

  .field4 {
    background-color: #a9c91b;
  }

  .field5 {
    background-color: #e8ff16;
  }

  .field6 {
    background-color: #00ff22;
  }
```